# change column letter in formula with drag down

Tags: drag-and-drop, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

This is the formula
=SUM(Sheet2!A2:A10)

What i've been trying to do is as I drag down the column to have the formula change to =SUM(Sheet2!B2:B10) and so on.

Basically is what happens we drag to the right we get an increment on the column letter, but I want it when I drag down

Comment: Still need help I've been searching everywhere for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For a limited number of rows, the formula below in Row2 and copied down should work:

> =SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"2:"&CHAR(64+ROW())&10))

Beyond 26 rows I would suggest switching to using a helper column instead of creating teh character value from the row number.